# How to make placeholder for the select option but it has loop value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, web

I've done the loops of the select option , but i had to make the place holder

What i'm trying to say is that it has the placeholder in the first value of select, the next value is the value that i loop

the code i've been made

```js
var start = 2010;
var end = 2030;
var options = "";
for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
  options += "<option>" + year + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("idBulanBerlaku").innerHTML = options;
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <select class="form-control" id="idBulanBerlaku">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It appears to work correctly, assuming you target the correct element with `getElementById()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding your requirement, you need to have a placeholder in your select. If you use `innerHTML`, it will wipe out the whole.

You can use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), like

```
document.getElementById("idBulanBerlaku").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", options);
```

**or** just below if you wish to keep using `innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById("idBulanBerlaku").innerHTML += options;
```

```js
var start = 2010;
var end = 2030;
var options = "";
for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
  options += "<option>" + year + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("idBulanBerlaku").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", options);
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <select class="form-control" id="idBulanBerlaku">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", options);

what's the beforeend mean? the options is the html element right?

Comment: beforeend means you are specifying to append the HTML before the select ends. options are the generated HTML from the loop

Comment: There are more variations to the function as well 'beforebegin','afterbegin','beforeend','afterend

Comment: @PiPio Please don't forget to accept the answer... Good day :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add more option like that. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
var start = 2010;
var end = 2030;
var options = "";
for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
  options += "<option>" + year + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("idBulanBerlaku").innerHTML += options;
```